# ffmpeg наложение картинки на видео

Tags: ffmpeg

есть video.mp4 и logo.png,
действие: накладываю логотип с 60 по 64 секунду видео с плавным появлением и затуханием:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 1 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=st=60:n=12:alpha=1, fade=out:st=64:n=12:alpha=1 [logo]; [0:v][logo] overlay=1:1" -y output.mp4
```

проблема в том, что рендер продолжается бесконечно, копируя последний кадр исходного видео и присоединяя его к выходному видео... подскажите, где копать...

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся с тем же и решил с помощью изменения loop-параметра, выставив его равным длине видео. Для вашего примера, если видео двух-минутное (120 секунд):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -loop 120 -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1:v] fade=st=60:n=12:alpha=1, fade=out:st=64:n=12:alpha=1 [logo]; [0:v][logo] overlay=1:1" -y output.mp4
```